# how to use limited ElementType for component in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, components

I want to create a polymorphic react component that can be limited ElementTypes.

I created this types for polymorphic components

```
type ComponentWithElementProps<Props, E extends React.ElementType | React.JSX.Element> = Props & Omit<React.ComponentProps<E>, keyof Props>

type PolymorphicComponentProps<Props, E extends React.ElementType | React.JSX.Element> = {as?: E} & Props & ComponentWithElementProps<Props, E>
```

and I used in my component

```
type FooOwnProps = {
  someProp: string
}

type FooProps<E extends React.ElementType = 'div'> = PolymorphicComponentProps<TestOwnProps, E>

function Foo<E extends React.ElementType = 'div'>({as, ...props}: FooProps<E>) {
  const Com = as || 'div'
  return (
    <Com {...props}>Test</Com>
  )
}
```

and its fine.

but I want to that as prop in Foo component accepts limited types for example only get <p> and <h1> tags. so I extract my limited element types from React.ElementType

`type LimitedElementType = Extract<React.ElementType, 'h1' | 'p'>`

and I used in my Foo component

```
type LimitedElementType = Extract<React.ElementType, 'h1' | 'p'>

type FooProps<E extends ElementType> = PolymorphicComponentProps<FooOwnProps, E>

function Foo<E extends LimitedElementType = 'p'>({as, ...props}: FooProps<E>) {
  const Com = as || 'p'
  return (
    <Com {...props}>Test</Com>
  )
}
```

this is ok for elements that have same attributes like h1 and p. but not ok for elements that have different attributes like label and a

`type LimitedElementType = Extract<React.ElementType, 'a' | 'label'>`

and I got this errors

```
Type 'Omit<Foo<E>, "as"> & { children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ((ClassAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & ClassAttributes<...> & LabelHTMLAttributes<...> & ClassAttributes<...> & HTMLAttributes<...>) | LibraryManagedAttributes<...>)'.
  Type 'Omit<Foo<E>, "as"> & { children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ClassAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & ClassAttributes<...> & LabelHTMLAttributes<...> & ClassAttributes<...> & HTMLAttributes<...>'.
    Type 'Omit<Foo<E>, "as"> & { children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ClassAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
      Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'Foo<E>["ref"] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined'.
          Type 'ComponentProps<E>["ref"]' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined'.
            Type 'string | ((instance: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLAnchorElement> | ((instance: HTMLLabelElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined'.
              Type '(instance: HTMLLabelElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined'.
                Type '(instance: HTMLLabelElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLAnchorElement | null) => void'.
                  Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
                    Type 'HTMLAnchorElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLLabelElement | null'.
                      Type 'HTMLAnchorElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLLabelElement': control, form, htmlForts(2322)
```

and it is funny because my component is still works

```
// both of this components are works
<Foo as="a" href='' />
<Foo as="label" htmlFor='' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to getting it working using something similar to the following, not sure if it's the best method but it has worked for now.

```
type AllowedElements = 'a' | 'label'
type IsAllowedElement<T> = T extends React.ElementType<AllowedElements> ? T : never

type BaseProps<T extends React.ElementType> = {
  as?: IsAllowedElement<T>
}

type Props<T extends React.ElementType> = BaseProps<T> &
  Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithRef<T>, keyof BaseProps<T>>

type Component = <T extends React.ElementType>(
  props: Props<T>,
) => React.ReactNode

export const Text: Component = forwardRef(
  <T extends React.ElementType = 'a'>(
    { as, ...props }: Props<T>,
    ref: React.ComponentPropsWithRef<T>['ref'],
  ) => {
    const Component = as || 'a'

    return <Component {...props />
  }
)
```